# The Google login code doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a game for Android. So I wrote the code that about Google Play login system and add it to `0th` scene using as GameManager.

But I don't know why this code doesn't work.
I mean, the game just stops at `0th` scene that I add the login code.

```
void Start () 
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

    Initialize();

    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
    {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sign in successful!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Failed to sign in with Google Play");
        }
    });
}

public void Initialize()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = false;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
}
```

Comment: You have to try that on your **DEVICE, not on SIMULATOR**. Refer to https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2017/01/22/using-firebase-in-unity3d-tutorial-2-authorization-and-user-login-example-with-user-name-and-password/. You will find similar solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I already uploaded it at play store as alpha. That mean I already tested it with my device. But I couldn't find the solution for this problem so I added a question at here.